# Externally triggering an Actions On Google app to start

Tags: actions-on-google

Here is my scenario: I have some code that is triggered by an event. The code and trigger are completely external to Google Assistant. I want this code to somehow trigger the Google Assistant on my device to start my Actions On Google app.

Here's a use case. I use IFTTT to send an HTTP request to my web server whenever I leave home. I want the web server to then trigger the Google Assistant on my phone to ask me where I'm going.

Comment: Notifications are not entirely ready, but you can check the developer preview to learn how to implement them: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates